# Display a specific subcategory product using PHTML

Tags: magento

what should be the code in phtml file to show one specific subcategory product on home page ?

I have created a file in catalog/product/topSection.phtml with following code-

```
             <?php

                $cat_id = 42;
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
                $products = $category->getProductCollection();
                echo 'total- '.$products->count();
                foreach($products as $product){ ?>


                <h3>
                  <img src="<?php echo $product->getImageUrl() ?>" alt="">
                  <p><?php echo $product->getName()  ?></p>
                </h3>

            <?php }?>
```

and used

> {{block type="core/template" name="top.section.home" template="catalog/product/topSection.phtml"}}

in home page content. but nothing is displaying. what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Did you make sure that the products called and category are in the right store view scope ? also check this it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794046/how-do-display-products-by-category-in-cms-page-in-magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code it is working and also display product. First please check category id and  sure category is enable ?